# What is the simplest way to understand $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \textbf{A} ) =0$?

Tags: vector-analysis

Of course one can prove it by brute force.

But how to Understand it, in the simplest way?

Another issue is $\nabla \times (\nabla f) =0 $.

Comment: In the language of [differential forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form), both of these are specific cases of the fact that $d^2 = 0$, where $d$ represents the [exterior derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative).

Comment: If you've learned Stokes' theorem and the Divergence theorem, these together with the fundamental theorem of line integrals explain why these vanish.

Comment: No, I am a physicist. I do not want to plunge into differential geometry.

Comment: A surprising amount of physics these days takes a fair bit of knowledge of differential geometry. I can't speak for your specific field of knowledge, of course, but it's certainly not a bad thing to know just because you're a physicist.

Comment: If you're a physicist, you're going to have to learn a huge amount of differential geometry eventually. It's a huge part general relativity, gauge theory, and it even pops up in electromagnetism, quantum mechanics (through the Berry connection), etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a way to remember/understand. Think that $\nabla $ is a vector. Then, by definition, $\nabla \times A$ is perpendicular to $\nabla $ and so the product scalar of $\nabla $ and $\nabla \times A$ is nul, therefore
$$\nabla \cdot  (\nabla \times A)=0$$

Comment: True, but unlike real vectors which satisfy $\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{A} = 0$, the $\nabla$ operator does not, as can be shown $\nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf{A} \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an explanation based on Stokes' theorem, the Divergence theorem, and the fundamental theorem of line integrals. Recall that Stokes' theorem states that the line integral along a closed curve is equivalent to a certain surface integral of the surface enclosed:

$$\int_{\partial D} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\int_{D} (\nabla\times \mathbf{F})\cdot d\mathbf{S}$$

But the fundamental theorem of line integrals states that $\int_a^b(\nabla f)\cdot d\mathbf{r}=f(b)-f(a)$. So if $\mathbf{F}=\nabla f$ for some function $f$, then

$$\int_{D} (\nabla\times (\nabla f))\cdot d\mathbf{S}=\int_{\partial D} (\nabla f)\cdot d\mathbf{r}=f(b)-f(a)=0$$ since the endpoints coincide (it's a closed loop). So the surface integral vanishes for any surface $D$; the only way this can make sense is if $\nabla\times \nabla f=0$.

Similarly, recall that the Divergence Theorem states that we may express the flux integral over the surface of a volume $V$ as

$$\int_{\partial V} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\int_V (\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F})dV$$

Now, if $\mathbf{F}=\nabla\times \mathbf{A}$, then Stokes' theorem implies that we may write this as a line integral of $\mathbf{A}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$ along the boundary of the surface $\partial V$---but this surface has no boundary! So the integral vanishes immediately. (If that seems too quick, cut the surface integral in two and show that the two line integrals obtained from Stokes' theorem cancel.) Therefore the volume integral over $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}=\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times \mathbf{A})$ vanishes for any volume $V$, and so we must have $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{(\nabla\times \mathbf{A})}=0$.